# Is the outlook REST API throttling me?

Tags: outlook-restapi

I have created a basic script which checks for an email in my inbox, and yesterday everything was working fine. But today all i get is a HTTP404 when I run the same code.

I suspect that outlook.office365.com might be throttling my requests since I ran this 1 time every minute for about 36 hours. But how can i tell if that is the case?

Here are my curl command:

```
curl https://outlook.office365.com/api/1.0/Me/folders/Inbox/messages -u login@email.outlook:password --insecure --show-error -H Content-Type:application/json -v
```

and the output:

```
* About to connect() to outlook.office365.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 132.245.48.18... connected
* Connected to outlook.office365.com (132.245.48.18) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=WA; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation;     OU=Microsoft Corporation; CN=outlook.com
*        start date: 2015-02-13 00:38:15 GMT
*        expire date: 2016-02-13 00:38:15 GMT
*        subjectAltName: outlook.office365.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation;     OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA1
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'login@email.outlook'
> GET /api/1.0/Me/folders/Inbox/messages HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic Ybase64stringU=
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3     OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: outlook.office365.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< request-id: d7967869-c282-4a28-9da2-6b80edd7d965
< Set-Cookie: ClientId=XXQW0EIP0KK9NUIRICS8BQ; expires=Fri, 28-Oct-2016     13:04:08 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< X-CalculatedBETarget: AM2PR09MB0452.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com
< X-BackEndHttpStatus: 404
< X-DiagInfo: AM2PR09MB0452
< X-BEServer: AM2PR09MB0452
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< X-FEServer: HE1PR01CA0033
< Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 13:04:08 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host outlook.office365.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had exceeded a quota, I would expect you would receive a `429` status code. Microsoft don't usually publish an exact threshold for their services as they reserve the right to adjust them...

> so users can consume the maximum number of resources without degrading the reliability and performance

(The above quote is specifically in respect of Sharepoint, but given the lack of published limits for pretty much all REST APIs I imagine the principle holds).

The `404` would usually indicate something isn't quite right... if your user account was reasonably new it could indicate it hadn't propagated to all servers yet (although in your case that doesn't seem to be the issue as you must have had the account for >24 hours).

From a URL point of view... the v1 URL is `outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages` and the new beat URL is `outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages` these addresses seem to work for me... but I get a 404 if I use the address you are using... so double-check the URL.

Comment: Ah, think it was a combination of things. I had created the code using the `/ews/odata` api and it was not working anymore suddenly returning 404. So i updated it to `/api/1.0` and as you pointed out made a typo. Once I changed it to v1.0 it worked once more. Thank you!